# How to have countries,cities, regions and subregions in a Django Project

Tags: django, localization, geolocation

I'm developing a simple website in Django. The main function of the WebApp is to store user information like:

- Country of the User
- City of the User
- Region (of the Country) of the User
- Sub-region (of the Country) of the User
- District (of the Country) of the User

In my search for solutions I've found one. To use the http://www.geonames.org/ database.

In relation to Django specifically I've found a two Django Apps:

1. https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities
2. https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light

I'm currently testing `django-cities` and I've lost two days trying to import the data. The App is unmaintained and modifications must to be done so the App runs on Django 4 and until now I've not been successful to make it work.

My question here on SO is mainly to ask for help about options. Is GeoNames the only option?

The Django community have other options than `django-cities` and `django-cities-light`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at 'django-address'?

Answer (score 0):

[django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) is maintained and works with Django 4. Just be careful to the installations instructions that are misleading: the package itself is not up to date on Pypi, so you need to install the project using the github repository.

Something like:
`pip install git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git` should work